# axios post request not sending data after submit

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm having troube with my post request, for some reason it doesn't seem to be sending the data its supposed to. When I submit the request I get a `status 201` which is great but when I check the `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` the post I send doesn't come up.

Here is my code, I have recreated it in a sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-thunder-322xi?file=/src/components/FormComponent.js

Can someone help me out please, thank you?

Comment: You can't create a resource on jsonpalceholder's server using `POST` method. API just fakes it that the resource has been created. See the note under [jsonplaceholder - Create a resource](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide.html)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSONPlaceholder guide](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide.html) state that you will get the correct response, but data will not be persisted.

> Important: the resource will not be really updated on the server but it will be faked as if.
>
> *(source: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide.html)*

To actually save your data you need to create your own copy of the service. For this use: [https://github.com/typicode/json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#json-server--).

Comment: What do you mean by "create your own copy of the service"?

Comment: I mean run the JSON Server locally. The [Getting Started](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#getting-started) guide of the [JSON Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) explains how you can do this.